# How to create a registry key

Tags: windows, registry, nsis

How can I create a registry key with NSIS? I couldn't find the appopriate command in NSIS doc.

(I understand all security issues)

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to install "Registry plug-in" for using registry key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install NSIS [Registry plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Registry_plug-in#Create_Registry_Key)

Use following function to Create registry keys.

```
Create Registry Key
${registry::CreateKey} "[fullpath]" $var
$var == 1   # [fullpath] already exists
$var == 0   # [fullpath] successfully created
$var == -1  # error
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create a empty registry key with the native NSIS instructions but the key is created for you when you set a value:

```
WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Test" "" "The Default"

;or

WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Test" "Foo" "Bar"
```